# Git shows error "bad config file in line 2"

Tags: git, github, gitlab, config

how should i config the file properly for both accounts. my gitconfig file for github

```
[github]
Host github.com
   HostName github.com
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github
   User git
   IdentitiesOnly yes

[gitlab]
Host gitlab.com
   HostName gitlab.com
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
   User git
   IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've put this content into the `.gitconfig` file in your home directory.  That configuration file is for Git configuration, but the configuration you've specified is for SSH.  You should take this content out of `~/.gitconfig` and put it in `~/.ssh/config` instead, where it can be used by `ssh` when you're pushing to Git repositories.